# SQL table performance issue(many-to-many)

Tags: sql, database, performance

I want to know what courses each student chose.
Assume that we have two tables: **student** and **lesson**:

```
-----student-----

| ID | name | my_lessons |
| 1  | John | 1;3;6      |
| 2  | Jack | 4;5;6      |
| .  |  .   |   .        |
| .  |  .   |   .        |
| n  |  .   |   .        |
```

```
----lesson------

| lesson_ID | lesson_name |
| 1         | English     |
| 2         | Math        |
| .         |  .          |
| .         |  .          |
| m         |  .          |
```

So the SQL command is:

```
$list = student's my_lessons
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `lesson` WHERE `lesson_ID` IN ($list)");
```

However, its performance would be bad if the student/lesson number is big.
Is there a better table design for this case?

Comment: Normally you would use a separate table for the *student has lessons* relation. And with proper (foreign) keys, performance of a join would not be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a many-to-many relationship (each student can have some lessons and each lesson can be taken by some students)

So use another table to link them. You have a Student Table

```
| student_ID | name |
```

and a Lesson Table

```
| lesson_ID | lesson_name |
```

and a Register Table (in which each row shows a student takes a lesson )

```
| student_ID | lesson_ID |
```

Now, You can find the lessons of student with ID=x like this:

```
Select lesson_name
from lesson,register
where lesson.lesson_id=register.lesson_id and student_id=x
```